# Preventing multiple form submits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am submitting a form using JQuery and an event listener bound to a div (not an input field) and I am trying to prevent multiple submits, so the customer does not get overcharged. I am trying to accomplish this by removing the `submit-button` class of the clicked div, so the next time the user clicks it, JQuery won't listen to the event that is associated with the `submit-button` preventing multiple submits.

Using the implementation below however, for some reason, does not prevent multiple submits, as intended.

HTML

```
<div class="submit-button button-style">Submit</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".submit-button").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("submit-button");
    //**submit form**
});
```

NOTE: I must stick to a solution that uses the html above, so solutions using an `input` element of type `submit`, will not be useful.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to make this work. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So now you're having to deal with re-validation and re-rendering. Let me just make this simple: if you want this to work correctly, *do it correctly*. That means "an `input` element of type `submit`". It *exists* to handle this use case. You can put your users through the joy your re-learning what web browser devs have exhaustively debugguged over the last 15 years if you want, or you can just do it correctly. I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: I appreciate the reply.If it were my choice, I would chosen the correct way using an `input` field. However, even with the `input` field approach, some measures need to be made to prevent multiple form submits, it is not automatic.

Comment: @AdamKG Pah! Don't you know that accessibility is for the weak! Convoluted designs promote CONFORMITY in your user base. And if they don't like it, well they can simply open up the console and write their own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `.one()` to prevent it from firing multiple times -

```
$(".submit-button").one('click',function(){
    //**submit form**
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Edit :

In case of error :

```
function submitForm(){
    //**submit form**
   $.post('submit.php').error(function(){
        // rebind event on error
        $(".submit-button").one('click',submitForm);
   });
}
$(".submit-button").one('click',submitForm);
```

Comment: beat me by 13 seconds!!

Comment: +1, Thanks for the suggestion! This seems useful, I never heard of `one()` :)  however, there is a minor problem, if there are server errors, I need to re-enable for an additional one try... any suggestions here?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend In case of error, you can re-bind event with `.one()`

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by re-bind event, I apologize I am pretty new to all this, can you please show an example? I appreciate the help :)

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Are you using ajax for form submit ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
$('something').one('click', function(){
   // submit code
});
```

Which will only fire once.

Answer (score 0):

A significant portion of users don't bother clicking the submit button to submit a form - there's other more convenient ways, like hitting the enter key when the cursor focus is on a form field.

A more robust approach is to block the form via the forms submit event, and maintain a variable to keep track of the form submission state.

```
var submitted = false;
$("form#myForm").submit(function(evt){
    if (submitted) {
        evt.preventDefault();//stops form submission
        return;
    }

    submitted = true;
});
```

I omitted form validation for this example.